# SmartStore styled dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not a designer by working nature. I'm a developer who write codes mostly and working on MVC project.

I am trying to create simple dropdownlist in MVC as per the screenshot.

[image: SmartStore dropdownlist]

The dropdownlist can be viewed at [SmartStore frontend register](http://frontend.smartstore.net/en/register). The source code and designs are available at [SmartStore Codeplex releases](http://smartstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/113222) and they are using Bootstrap and MVC along with CSS.

I tried my best to found the script that is making dropdownlist to show month names. But unable to found it out. I can copy design using their source code but cannot replicate functionality in my own website.

Can you please guide me how to design same styled dropdownlist with same functionality?

Comment: have a look at [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: Perfect! I wish I could mark your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) library.

A example of that :

```
<head>
    <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { $("#e1").select2(); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="e1">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        ...
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</body>
```